# Generate sequential number whenever user input into a scanner (Java)

Tags: java, numbers, java.util.scanner, sequential

I'm currently a newbie on Java and im trying to figure out how to generate a sequential number whenever a user inputs into a scanner. Currently I've been baffling between using atomicint and atomiclong for their number generator . However, my point is that whenever a user-entered all the necessary data from the class (Id,name,email,phone..etc) , it will auto-assign that user as Guest_01 at the beginning of the console
(e.g Guest_01: s4842(ID),Jason Schlong(name),JasonSC234@gmail.com(email))
Is there a specific method to illustrate the output above?
(Please keep in mind that i need to generate the sequential number first before putting it into a scanner(sounds dumb but that's how i did it )

```
public class Main {

private static final int  TOTAL_NUMBER_IN_SEQUENCE =20;
private static final int  TOTAL_NUMBER_IN_THREAD =50;


public static void main(String[] args) {
   Lead lead = new Lead(TOTAL_NUMBER_IN_THREAD,TOTAL_NUMBER_IN_SEQUENCE);
   Thread t1 = new Thread(new SequenceGenerator(lead,1),"Lead_");
   Thread t2 = new Thread(new SequenceGenerator(lead,3),"Lead_");
   Thread t3 = new Thread(new SequenceGenerator(lead,2),"Lead_");
   t1.start();
   t2.start();
   t3.start();


}
```

---

```
public class SequenceGenerator implements Runnable{
public Lead lead;
public int result;


public SequenceGenerator(Lead lead, int result) {
    super();
    this.lead = lead;
    this.result = result;
}
public void run(){
    lead.printNumber(result);
}
```

}

---

```
public class Lead {
private int number = 1;
private int NumberofThread;
private int totalNumbersequence;

public Lead(int numberofThread, int totalNumbersequence) {
    super();
    NumberofThread = numberofThread;
    this.totalNumbersequence = totalNumbersequence;
}
public void printNumber(int resutl){
    synchronized (this){
        while(number < totalNumbersequence-1){
            while (number % NumberofThread!= resutl){
                try {
                    wait();
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+number++);
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Please feel free to post it.

Comment: @Jason i have input the code. Sorry for not insert it because there is a lot of stuffs going on and I've been watching some indian dude generating number by using class so there is a lot of progress going on here .My apology

Comment: Can you provide the `SequenceGenerator` class and `Lead` class?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about what the problem is. Is it that it's not generating ID's sequentially or is the problem the format of the name? Can you update the post to be a bit more clear if possible.

Comment: @Jason it is not generating ID number and my question is if there is a simpler way on generating a sequential number  whenever a user finished input their data

Comment: Do you have to use 3 threads? Can you use a single thread?

Comment: @Jason yes I can use 1 thread. It just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this multi-threaded approach. You can just maintain an integer and every time you create a guest you simply increment it.

```java
    static final class Guest {
        
        private final int sequenceId;

        private final String id;

        private final String name;

        private final String email;

        Guest(int sequenceId, String id, String name, String email) {
            this.sequenceId = sequenceId;
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public int getSequenceId() {
            return sequenceId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Guest_%s: %s, %s, %s", 
                    sequenceId, id, name, email);
        }
    }
```

```java
    private Guest createGuest(int sequence) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        String id = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter email:");
        String email = scanner.nextLine();

        return new Guest(sequence, id, name, email);
    }
```

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuestGenerator generator = new GuestGenerator();

        int sequence = 0;

        while (sequence < 2) {
            Guest guest = generator.createGuest(sequence++);

            System.out.println(guest);
        }
    }
```

```
Guest_0: 0, jason0, email0
Guest_1: 0, jason1, email1
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the structure however it is possible to add another argument into toString() because im testing out whether i can get more input such as Gender,phonenumber etc

Comment: Yeah it is possible. Feel free to research and also review how I did it.

Comment: thanks i figure it out and get the class ready but however i might ask , where is the GuestGenerator comes from

Comment: That is just the class that I put those methods in, including main(String[]), it literally could be named anything.